FullCalendar: How to set column header date format
I tried like this with columnFormat:
                    <FullCalendar
                        ref={calendarRef}
                        plugins={[
                            dayGridPlugin,
                            timeGridPlugin,
                            listPlugin,
                            interactionPlugin,
                        ]}
                        columnFormat={{
                            week: 'ddd M/D', // Customize the format as per your preference
                        }}

but get this error:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: CalendarOptions | Readonly<CalendarOptions>): FullCalendar', gave the following error.
    Type '{ ref: RefObject<FullCalendar>; plugins: PluginDef[]; titleFormat: { month: "short"; week: undefined; day: "2-digit"; }; columnFormat: { week: string; }; initialView: string; ... 12 more ...; eventDrop: (dropInfo: { ...; }) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<FullCalendar> & Readonly<CalendarOptions> & Readonly<...>'.
      Property 'columnFormat' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<FullCalendar> & Readonly<CalendarOptions> & Readonly<...>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: CalendarOptions, context: any): FullCalendar', gave the following error.
    Type '{ ref: RefObject<FullCalendar>; plugins: PluginDef[]; titleFormat: { month: "short"; week: undefined; day: "2-digit"; }; columnFormat: { week: string; }; initialView: string; ... 12 more ...; eventDrop: (dropInfo: { ...; }) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & 

I would make date shorter, to look good on mobile.


I tried like this with columnFormat...why? Clearly there is no such setting - check the documentation . Was this just a random guess?

You can control this with https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dayHeaderFormat

You can edit the header by utilising the content injection dayHeaderContent, you can read more about this here
When returning the content injected input you can add a style to the component. This should allow you to override the default behaviour.
for example:
dayHeaderContent={(args) => {
    return <div className={...your required class}>{args.date}</div>
}}


OP isn't asking to change the visual effect, they want to adjust the generation of the date string, for which there is already a dedicated setting.
